# How to find the root cause of memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

Sometime, when I close my app I have this error :

```
---------------------------
Unexpected Memory Leak
---------------------------
An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:
    
21 - 28 bytes: TGradientPoints x 2, TGradientPoint x 4, Unknown x 2
29 - 36 bytes: TD2DBitmapHandle x 1, TGradient x 2, TBitmapImage x 3, TBrushBitmap x 2
37 - 44 bytes: TFont x 1, TList<System.Classes.TCollectionItem> x 2, TBrushResource x 2, TPosition x 12
45 - 52 bytes: TBitmap x 3, TObjectList<FMX.Graphics.TCanvasSaveState> x 1, UnicodeString x 1
53 - 60 bytes: TBrush x 1
61 - 68 bytes: Unknown x 1
69 - 76 bytes: TTransform x 2
77 - 84 bytes: TStrokeBrush x 1
237 - 252 bytes: TCanvasD2D x 1
    
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The problem is that I can't find out from where those memory leaks come from and as this exception raise very rarely it's very hard to debug. :(

Is their any good way to find the root cause of memory leak?

Comment: Use the full FastMM4 library with a stack tracer like madExcept, eureka or jcldebug

Comment: From this log, TCanvas2D2 is the one to look for. Check what you were doing in the code - what allocates TCanvas2D2?

Answer (score -3):

The option is to use FASTMM5 instead of the default FastMM4 included in Delphi.

With FastMM5, we can do:

```
if FastMM_LoadDebugSupportLibrary then
begin
  FastMM_EnterDebugMode;
  FastMM_MessageBoxEvents := FastMM_MessageBoxEvents + [mmetUnexpectedMemoryLeakDetail];
end;
```

Then at shutdown, we have the exact stack trace of each memory leak.

Comment: You can get stack traces with FastMM4. As you know FastMM5 license is dual GPL or commercial

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes you are totally right, we can do the same with fastmm4. FastMM5 is not free, but pierre le riche do a wonderfull job in it so I don't care to gave him few $ for his job. madExcept and eureka are not free either :(

Comment: @zeus But worth every single penny (or cent or whatever) !

Comment: @DelphiCoder yes I already bought the licence of madexcept too :)